# Print array in MsgBox remove trailing comma

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an array that get displayed in `msgBox` via `Join()` function. I wonder how I can remove a trailing comma that appears if I use a `Join` on `resultsFinal` array.

```
Function test2(Var As Range)
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim resultsFinal() As String
    ReDim resultsFinal(0)
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0

    result = 0

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Var.Cells
            If cell.Value = 25 Or cell.Value = 45 Then
                   result = result + 1
                   ReDim Preserve resultsFinal(result)
                   Dim temp As String

                   resultsFinal(i) = cell.Row
                   i = i + 1
                   test2 = cell.Value
            End If
    Next cell

    Dim resultsFinal1() As String   'here is my try
    resultsFinal1 = resultsFinal  
    ReDim Preserve resultsFinal1(result - 1)  'the length is smaller!
    MsgBox result & " and " & vbNewLine & "array: " & Join(resultsFinal1, ", ")   'still displayes the full array, including the last character (but fortunately somehow doesn't display comma)

End Function
```

Also I tried to create a `resultsFinal1` array that is an initial array minus the last element. It works, but not as expected - somehow although the length of the `resultsFinal1` is smaller than that of `resultsFinal`, it still stores the last element, and the comma disappears. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your array is always bigger by 1, because array indexes start from 0. So in actuality Redim resultsFinal(0) creates an array with 1 element.

So by swapping lines from

```
result = result + 1
ReDim Preserve resultsFinal(result)
```

to

```
ReDim Preserve resultsFinal(result)
result = result + 1
```

your array size becomes correct.

For second part, keyword `Join` adds a string **between** array items, so when you had your array 1 bigger, it added a `,` between your last correct element in the array and an empty string, which was actually the last item in your array.

Comment: Thank you, I see know. I thought ReDim Preserve array(n) makes an array of size n, not the array that has n+1 elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was that you  incremented the `result` variable too early. Try this code and see if it does what you want. I basically removed all your code for `resultsFinal1` and move the `result = result + 1` to after the `ReDim` of the `resultFinal` array.

```
Function test2(Var As Range)
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim resultsFinal() As String
    ReDim resultsFinal(0)
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0

    result = 0

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Var.Cells
            If cell.Value = 25 Or cell.Value = 45 Then
                   ReDim Preserve resultsFinal(result)
                   result = result + 1
                   Dim temp As String

                   resultsFinal(i) = cell.Row
                   i = i + 1
                   test2 = cell.Value
            End If
    Next cell

    MsgBox result & " and " & vbNewLine & "array: " & Join(resultsFinal, ", ")   'still displayes the full array, including the last character (but fortunately somehow doesn't display comma)

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code provided the same, right result. What I don't get is how can you create an array with length zero: `ReDim resultsFinal(0)` and then put a value into it: `resultsFinal(i)=cell.Row`?

Comment: `ReDim resultsFinal(0)` actually creates an array with one item in it. The array has a 0 based index meaning `ReDim resultsFinal(0)` creates an array with 1 item and `ReDim resultsFinal(1)` creates an array with two items

Answer (score 1):

I'm not by my PC so this is a blind guess but I suspect that has to do with the fact you aren't using Option Explicit statement and so all not declared variables (like "resultsFinal") get implicitly dimmed as of Variant type an therefore when you assign it an array it has first index of zero and the last index of "result"-1 so that when you are resizing it to "result"-1 it has no real effect of resizing!

You may want to try this (untested) code

```
Option Explicit

Function test2(Var As Range)
    Dim result As Integer
    ReDim resultsFinal(1 to Var.Count) As String

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Var.Cells
        If cell.Value = 25 Or cell.Value = 45 Then
               result = result + 1
               resultsFinal(result) = cell.Row
        End If
    Next cell
    If result > 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve resultsFinal(1 to result - 1)  'resize the array one element less then those stored
        MsgBox result & " and " & vbNewLine & "array: " & Join(resultsFinal, ", ") 
    Else
        MsgBox "No items found!"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: misses adding the last value to the array list on my testing?

Comment: @brettdj, I don't get you: what's the issue?

Comment: Code captures the number of matches, but misses reporting the last matched row.

Comment: @brettdj, which is what I got OP wanted to do. Didn't he?

Answer (score 0):

One liner without loops:

```
Function test2(Var As Range)
test2 = "Found 25 in " & Join(Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF(" & Var.Address & "=25,ROW(" & Var.Address & "),""x"")")), "x", False), ",") & _
    vbNewLine & "Found 45 in " & Join(Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=IF(" & Var.Address & "=45,ROW(" & Var.Address & "),""x"")")), "x", False), ",")
End Function
```

*test*

```
Sub TEST()
MsgBox test2(Range("A1:a100"))
End Sub
```